# Want to hide all tags after 3 tags and work with all other also like if i use one more time HTML code it work with first one and also with the second

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Any comment or answer will be helpful plz**

**Issues**

*You can see from code that it can be hide on click of button of given html code but the issues are:*

- Want to **hide lists** at **start** and then **show/hide** on **further click**
- If **HTML** code is written **2 times** or more times then **clicking** on second code button **Show More 2** it will **change** the **first one only** but I **want** that it to **happen separately** without writing **Java Script** code **differently** and **again every time**
- **Bug :** You have to double click Show More button first time to show the li tag then it works fine ---- **Removed By tacoshy**

**HTML**
*If i write html 2 times then the java script apply for both of them diferently.*
*It will be very helpful plz*

```html
<ul class="deviceNameCardData" id="deviceNameCardData">
  <li>Windows 11</li>
  <li>8GB Ram</li>
  <li>1TB SSD</li>
  <li>Intel Core i7 (11th Gen)</li>
  <li>NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050</li>
  <li>15.6 inch Full HD Display</li>
  <li>Dolby Audio</li>
  <li>1 Year Onsite Warranty</li>
</ul>
<button id="demo" onclick="reed(this)">Show More</button>
```

*when button is clicked two times it shows tags i want that on 1 click plz.*
*It will be very helpful plz to solve this bug*

**CSS**

*To cope with first issue I used this CSS code but it creates a another problem that bullets are disappeared from the lists items which are toggled*

```css
.deviceNameCardData.short > li:nth-child(n + 6) {
  display: block;
}
.deviceNameCardData > li:nth-child(n + 6) {
  display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

*Want to use same below code for every time whether there are 2 or 3 above html code.*
*Till now i can use only for 1 time for a code.*
*It will be very helpful plz*

```js
function reed() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("deviceNameCardData");
  button = document.getElementById("demo");
  ul.classList.toggle("short");
  if (button.innerHTML == "Show More") {
    button.innerHTML = "Show Less";
  } else {
    button.innerHTML = "Show More";
  }
}
```

**Code Snippet:**

```js
function reed() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("deviceNameCardData")
  button = document.getElementById("demo")
  ul.classList.toggle("short")
  if (button.innerHTML == 'Show More') {
    button.innerHTML = 'Show Less';
  } else {
    button.innerHTML = 'Show More';
  }
}
```

```css
.deviceNameCardData.short>li:nth-child(n+6) {
  display: block;
}

.deviceNameCardData>li:nth-child(n+6) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="deviceNameCardData" id="deviceNameCardData">
  <li>Windows 11</li>
  <li> 8GB Ram</li>
  <li>1TB SSD</li>
  <li>Intel Core i7 (11th Gen)</li>
  <li>NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050</li>
  <li>15.6 inch Full HD Display</li>
  <li> Dolby Audio</li>
  <li>1 Year Onsite Warranty</li>
</ul>
<button id="demo" onclick="reed(this)">Show More</button>
```

Comment: The main problems are you have to click two times on button to show first time tags. Secondly ,if the html code is used 2 time then whenever button is clicked it works for 1st one only not second one. If you provide java script it will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

First at all create a class that hides all list-items with exeption of the first 3 list-items. In my snippet is used the class: `short`.

You can hide all the lsit items with exeption of the first 3 by using `:nth-of-type(n+4)` selector. This will select all items starting at the 4th item.

it is far easier and less buggy to just declare `display: none;` to hide those elements instead of changing the `font-size` to `0`.

Then use a script to add/remove the class to/from the list when then button is pressed:

```js
function reed() {
  var ul = document.querySelector('.deviceNameCardData'),
      button = document.querySelector('#demo');
      
  // toggles the class of the ul
  ul.classList.toggle('short');
  
  // toggles the button inner text
  if (button.innerHTML == 'Show More') {
    button.innerHTML = 'Show Less';
  } else {
    button.innerHTML = 'Show More';
  }
}
```

```css
ul.short > li:nth-of-type(n+4) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="deviceNameCardData short" id="deviceNameCardData">
  <li>Windows 11</li>
  <li> 8GB Ram</li>
  <li>1TB SSD</li>
  <li>Intel Core i7 (11th Gen)</li>
  <li>NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050</li>
  <li>15.6 inch Full HD Display</li>
  <li> Dolby Audio</li>
  <li>1 Year Onsite Warranty</li>
</ul>
<button id="demo" onclick="reed()">Show More</button>
```

With this approach you also need far elss computing power as you dont have to cycle through every element. The hiding/showing is done through CSS and as such works on the first click not just the second.

Comment: What if we use the given html twice or thrice......then java script is added every time. So how to cope with that plz

Comment: you can add the script to the onlick within HTML directly. Also what do you mean with that? if you add this very HTML twice or trice it would be invalid because of the ID. Then what you want to achieve? that a all lsit are toggled?

Comment: Also i want to hide lists at the start and then show/hide on further click. Tried using CSS to first display : none  then toggle display : block but this make the bullets disappear

Comment: I mean to say that if I have to make such lists for say 10-20 products then I have to write Java Script code every time for each list separately but can it be simplified to once which can change on the click of button say which ever list button is clicked it will toggle that one